# Django + Tastypie + support utf8

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I trying to create a new django app with tastypie api support.

I have created a model:

```
class Lead(models.Model): 

    BERUFSSTATUS = (
        ("Rentner/-in", "Rentner/-in"),
        ("Schüler/-in", "Schüler/-in"),
    )

    employmentstatus = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, choices=BERUFSSTATUS)
```

The problem is, I trying to insert

```
"employmentstatus":"Schüler/-in"
```

I get this error:

```
 "Value u'Sch\\xfcler/-in' is not in list."
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the following at the beginning of the file -

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

This would set default encoding to Unicode.